# Java spring 'Hello World' example couldn't compile

Tags: java, spring

As a HelloWorld example, in my spring Beans.xml file, I have:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
      <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

The main file:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        obj.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The class file:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }
   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}

The error seems like this:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld]: Is the constructor accessible?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils (in module spring.beans) cannot access class com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld (in module HelloSpring) because module HelloSpring does not export com.tutorialspoint to module spring.beans
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at HelloSpring/com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
```

Other folks on this site got the same problem, and I've looked at it. However, I've tried all the answers provided but none of them solved my issue. I've used several versions of the path inside  and there's no empty line above the first line of my Beans.xml. What's the problem here?

Comment: Error says *"... module HelloSpring ..."*. Delete the `module-info.java` file. The [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm) doesn't have one. See image in Step 4.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much